# Where am i supposed to use `RegisterViewWithRegion` in Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm creating "layout" `View` which includes few `ContentControl` elements, which results in need for me to register a "default" control to be desplayed at start. As I realize `RegisterViewWithRegion` solves this problem, but I am not sure where I'm supposed to use it?

So far I have been using `RegisterViewWithRegion` inside constructor of layout's `ViewModel`, but this results in

> ArgumentException: Region with the given name is already registered: AuthContentRegion

error once `ViewModel` is constructed again (second time).

View:

```xml
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.NavRegion}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5" />
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.AuthContentRegion}"  Margin="5" />
</DockPanel>
```

View Model:

```
public AdminViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.NavRegion, typeof(Views.AdminNavView));
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.AuthContentRegion, typeof(Views.RailwayListView));
}
```

Essentially what I want is to have default `UserControl` registered as `ContentControl`/`Region` without getting any exceptions once `View`/`ViewModel` is constructed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing `IRegionMemberLifetime` with `KeepAlive` set to `false` seems to have fixed issue with exception.

Also i realized that `RegisterViewWithRegion`could be substituted with `RequestNavigate` method by calling it in `Loaded` event.

View:

```xml
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <views:AdminNavView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5" />
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.AuthContentRegion}"  Margin="5" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public class AdminViewModel : BindableBase, IRegionMemberLifetime
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public AdminViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        OnLoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnLoaded);
    }

    public bool KeepAlive => false;
    public ICommand OnLoadedCommand { get; }

    public void OnLoaded()
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.AuthContentRegion, NavigationPaths.RailwayListPath);
    }
}
```